# SIG33 when debugging native Android

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk, native

I'm using Android Studio to debug a NativeActivity app written in C++
In my C++ code the first thing I do in `android_main()` is wait 10 seconds for the debugger to attach. In the 'Debug' window I see:

```
Now Launching Native Debug Session
```

and then after a few seconds

```
Debugger attached to process 28458
```

and then right after it attaches, the debugger is stopped with a signal:

```
Signal: 33 (signal SIG33)
```

I press 'Resume Program' and then I get the same signal again and again for 7-8 times. After that, the program continues as expected, debugger attached and I am able to stop it at breakpoints.

What's the meaning of that SIG33? how can I prevent it?

Comment: what version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Android studio 1.3.1, NDK 10e

Comment: Just an idea: the signal 33 may be intended for the program, and your debugger should pass it. I know how to do this with gdb (`handle SIG33 nostop noprint noignore pass`) but not with the android studio debugger; hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Signal 33 is used internally by bionic for the backtrace facilities.

See [comment in __libc_current_sigrtmin.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/master/libc/bionic/__libc_current_sigrtmin.cpp#32).

```
// POSIX timers use __SIGRTMIN + 0.
// libbacktrace uses __SIGRTMIN + 1.
// libcore uses __SIGRTMIN + 2.
```

See definition of `__SIGRTMIN` for [generic](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/master/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-generic/signal.h#69), [arm](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/master/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-arm/asm/signal.h#69), [x86](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/master/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-x86/asm/signal.h#74), and [mips](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/master/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-mips/asm/signal.h#74).

```
#define __SIGRTMIN 32
```

I think that SIG33 is caused by gdb and gdb is not correctly ignoring it.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using lldb, not gdb but I guess lldb works the same way and this does happen only at the very start when lldb just attached to the process. Any idea why it would not ignore it?

Comment: what version of lldb are you using? It's probably not ignoring it because of a bug or it's compiled for another linux variant.

Comment: some crash happen, so the JVM need to print backtrace. the main problem is that what lead to crash when attaching gdb.

Answer (score 2):

Those can be ignored and/or silenced using below `GDB` command-line:

```
handle SIG33 nostop noprint
```

Answer (score 1):

SIG33 is used to signal about "threading libraries" by LLDB.

Excerpt from LLDB source:

```
AddSignal (33, "SIG33", false, false, false, "threading library internal signal 2");
```

But I don't seem to understand the reason why your code is getting this. May be due to some minor dependency issues.